# X11 forwarding over ssh for R: why this warning?

Tags: r, ssh, x11, netbsd

I need to use R (3.0.2 from pkgsrc) on a remote server (NetBSD) over a ssh connection with X11 forwarding. `plot(1)` is generating the expected graphic on my local machine, however R is also returning warnings in my terminal session as below.

```
> plot(1)
Warning messages:
1: In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  locale not supported by Xlib: some X ops will operate in C locale
2: In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  X cannot set locale modifiers
```

I don't know whether this bodes problems that I may encounter later, but I'd like to get everything set up and configured correctly. Would someone please clarify the meaning of the warnings and explain how to address them?

Edit for more info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64--netbsd (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
> names(X11Fonts())
[1] "serif"        "sans"         "mono"         "Times"        "Helvetica"   
[6] "CyrTimes"     "CyrHelvetica" "Arial"        "Mincho"
```

Comment: It is a font or encoding issue.  On the netBSD machine, what do you get for `sessionInfo()` and `names(X11Fonts())`?

Answer (score 0):

The errors are saying that the X11 graphics driver does not know what font to use (see [this discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/X11-fonts-problems-td4390438.html)).  By default, R installs with the C locale set.  For linux, you need to set a UTF-8 locale which is prefixed by the language.

For example, for the English in the US, you would set it to 'en_US.UTF-8'.

Try setting the system locale with the [`Sys.setlocale`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html) command like so:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8")
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

This can be done through the `.bashrc` configuration file like so:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

([source](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2012-January/008948.html))

Comment: I'm still getting the same error after setting the system locale as you advised, but this is clearly on the right track.

Comment: Try "LC_ALL" instead of "LC_TIME" (copy and paste without reading).

Comment: After using both the Sys.setlocale commands you indicated, R can't find any X11 fonts, so the plot renders without text (e.g. scale bars). I'm checking to see whether this is something I need to address in NetBSD/pkgsrc outside of R.

Comment: No luck. Still stuck.